# Rich Text Format Directory File to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, rtf

Is it possible to convert an RFTD (Rich Text Format Directory) package to an NSAttributedString in iOS? This is a package that includes an RTF (Rich Text Format) file plus other files like images that are included in the rich text file.

I can convert a normal RTF file like this but I don't know how to convert an RFTD package to an `NSData` object. I also don't know if it's then possible to convert that `NSData` object to an `NSAttributedString` object.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902313/read-rtfd-data-in-ios

Comment: That answer is from 2011. Has Apple added this capability to iOS since then?

Comment: It looks like all RTFD-related functions are deliberately cut off from iOS, but since RTFD is just a directory with a normal RTF file, you could try accessing it as such.

Comment: Yes, I can load the RTF file in that directory to an NSAttributedString but how would I attach the images in the directory to that string? Is there any information in the string that would tell me where to attach the images?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all RTFD-related functions are deliberately cut off from iOS, but since RTFD is just a directory with a normal RTF file, you could try accessing it as such.

If you need attachments, based on the [RTF docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html) it seems that you can find a marker "NeXTGraphic" inside the RTF file string

`{{\NeXTGraphic attachment \widthN \heightN} string}`

where "attachment" will be a file name.

Similar question here: [Read RTFD data in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902313/read-rtfd-data-in-ios)